# How to interrupt PIG from DUMP -ing a huge file/variable in grunt mode?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

How do we interrupt pig `dump` command (EDIT: when it has completed the MapReduce jobs and is now just displaying the result on grunt shell) without exiting the grunt shell?

Sometimes, if we dump a HUGE file by mistake, it goes on forever!
I know we can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop it but it also quits the grunt shell and then we have to write all the commands again.

Answer (score 1):

We can execute the following command in the grunt shell

kill jobid

We can find the job’s ID by looking at Hadoop’s JobTracker GUI, which lists all jobs currently running on the cluster. Note that this command kills a particular MapReduce job. If the Pig job contains other MapReduce jobs that do not depend on the killed MapReduce job, these jobs will still continue. If you want to kill all of the MapReduce jobs associated with a particular Pig job, it is best to terminate the process running Pig using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and then use this command to kill any MapReduce jobs that are still running.

Comment: This didn't work. The "job" runs only till PIG is evaluating the query results. As soon as PIG processing is done, the job ends and there is nothing left to kill. 
After that, PIG just gets busy displaying results on grunt stdout with no job attached to it.